# How to convert JSON in camel case back to pascal case in Web API?

Tags: serialization, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

I have returned `json` to `camelcase` using,

```
formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Like this:

```
Data : Contacts: [{ GivenName: "Matt", FamilyName:"Berry" }]
result json:  contacts: [{ givenName: "Matt", familyName:"Berry" }]
```

How can I get back the original data (pascal case data) in Web API?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you're trying to accomplish. Usually when the client passes data to the API you create a model that the JSON can bind to and that model uses .NET naming conventions. Something like: `public class NameRequest { public string GivenName { get; set; } public string FamilyName { get; set; } }` Then when the client sends a JSON object like the one above it will automatically map to the request contract.

Comment: client sends a json object return to controller contacts: [{ givenName: "Matt", familyName:"Berry" }] then i'll  perform server side operation in the controller. But the json propertyname not converted into "GivenName". So the exception showing "could not find property givenname", but if i removed the cameclcase serialization it's work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You should not be trying to manipulate the JSON that the client is sending directly. You should use a model class as in my first comment and let the model binder resolve the JSON into a .NET object which you can then work with more easily.

Assuming the client is sending you JSON that looks like the following:

> { givenName: "Matt", familyName:"Berry" }

You should create a .NET class to receive that request.

```
public class NameRequest
{
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
}
```

Now you declare the argument to your WebAPI method using the contract.

```
public IHttpActionResult ProcessNameRequest (NameRequest request)
{
    request.GivenName
    request.FamilyName
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i've tried using model class. but still facing same issue. the problem is when i access back to controller, the property name can't deserialized to "Givenname". so the exception is occured. i'm using the webapi odata. pls tell me any other suggestions.

Comment: I think you need to update your original question with what the JSON actually looks like that is being passed in, what your controller method looks like, and what the exception is. What I posted above will work just fine, assuming your JSON looks like what I posted. Clearly something about your environment is different than what I posted.